# How does defer and named return value work?

Tags: go

I just started learning Go and I got confused with one example about using defer to change named return value in the [The Go Blog - Defer, Panic, and Recover](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover).

The example says:

> 3. Deferred functions may read and assign to the returning function's named return values.
>
> In this example, a deferred function increments the return value i after the surrounding function returns. Thus, this function **returns 2**:

```
func c() (i int) {
    defer func() { i++ }()
    return 1
}
```

But as what I have learned from  [A Tour of Go - Named return values](https://tour.golang.org/basics/7)

> **A return statement without arguments** returns the named return values. This is known as a "naked" return.

I tested in the following code and in function `b` it returns 1 because it wasn't the "*A return statement without arguments*" case mentioned above.

```
func a() (i int) { // return 2
    i = 2
    return
}

func b() (i int) {  // return 1 
    i = 2
    return 1
}
```

So my question is in the first example, the surrounding function c has a named return value i, but the function `c` uses `return 1` which in the second example we can see it should have return 1 no matter what value `i` is. But why after `i` changes in the deferred function the `c` function returns the value of `i` instead the value 1?

As I was typing my question, I might have guessed the answer. Is it because:

```
return 1
```

is equals to:

```
i = 1
return
```

in a function with a named return value variable `i`?

Please help me confirm, thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> A defer statement pushes a function call onto a list. The list of saved calls is executed after the surrounding function returns. -- [The Go Blog: Defer, Panic, and Recover](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover)

Another way to understand the above statement:

> A defer statements *pushes* a function call onto a **stack**. The stack of saved calls *popped out (LIFO)* and deferred functions are invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns.

```
 func c() (i int) {
    defer func() { i++ }()
    return 1
}
```

After 1 is returned, the defer `func() { i++ }()` gets executed. Hence, in order of executions:

1. i = 1 (return 1)
2. i++ (defer func pop out from stack and executed)
3. i == 2 (final result of named variable i)

---

For understanding sake:

```
 func c() (i int) {
    defer func() { fmt.Println("third") }()
    defer func() { fmt.Println("second") }()
    defer func() { fmt.Println("first") }()

    return 1
}
```

Order of executions:

1. i = 1 (return 1)
2. "first"
3. "second"
4. "third"

Comment: Thanks, i understand the LIFO thing about defer,  actually i was having difficulty understand the named return value. now i'm clear!

Comment: _"executer after the function returns"_ is incorrect. The specs quite clearly state that _"deferred functions are invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns"_, not after. If defers were invoked after the return, they wouldn't be able to change the return value in the case of `func c`. The order of execution should then be: `i = 1` (assign) `i++` (defer increment) `return` return 2

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Fixed! :)

Comment: This is one of the interesting go "gotcha" that flew in my face.

Comment: The OP was asking about the reason why returned value was 2, which i was confused while reading the docs too. The `LIFO` nature of `defer` is pretty clear already. I guess it would be great if your answer focus more to address the  returned value. Thanks. What a nice feature from Go.

Answer (score 12):

According to the Go Specification:

[Return Statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements)
A "return" statement that specifies results sets the result parameters before any deferred functions are executed.

[Defer Statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)
"...deferred functions are invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns..."

So yes, as you assumed, the named return variable is assigned, then the deferred statement increments it.

I would add that named return parameters can lead to subtle bugs, and generally should be avoided unless there's no alternative.

Answer (score 7):

I think the confusion is about function in function how about if you classified like this:

```
  func main() {
      fmt.Println(c()) //the result is 5
  }

  // the c function returned value is named j
  func c() (j int)  {
      defer changei(&j)
      return 6
  }
  func changei(j *int) {
      //now j is 6 because it was assigned by return statement 
      // and if i change guess what?! i changed the returned value
      *j--;
  }
```

but if the return value is not named like this:

```
  func main() {
      fmt.Println(c()) //the result will become 6
  }

  // the c function returned value is not named at this time
  func c() int  {
      j := 1
      defer changei(&j)
      return 6
  }
  func changei(j *int) {
      //now j = 1
      // and if i change guess what?! it will not effects the returned value
      *j--;
  }
```

I hope this will clear the confusion and that is how i did happy Go coding

Comment: I guess what you meant was this: https://play.golang.org/p/5zBeF9hoOCn. You have to return j in c() function.

Answer (score 0):

This should explain it clearly!

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/59543#issuecomment-1503237782

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this named return value  function

```
func c() (i int) {
  defer func() { i++ }()
  return 1
}
```

will be compiled like this:

```
func c() int {
  defer func() { i++ }()
  i = 1
  return i
}
```