# Can I use an pointer to "error" to catch the return error?

Tags: go

I am writing some transaction begin/commit/rollback functions, and I want to pair the block to prevent forgot commit

I write like this:

```golang
func (foo *Foo) Bar() (err error) {

  foo.Begin()
  defer foo.End(&err)

  //some business code

  return
}

func (foo *Foo) End(eptr *error) {
  // if recover
  if r := recover(); r != nil {
    debug.PrintStack()
    *eptr = r.(error)
  }

  var err = *eptr
  if err != nil {
    foo.Rollback()
  } else {
    foo.Commit()
  }
}
```

It works, but it uses the "pointer to interface", I cannot find the specifications about pointer to interface.

So, I am not sure this code is OK enough. Could you give some suggestions?

---

thanks to teyzer and Corey Ogburn, this is my fixed solution:

```golang
func (foo *Foo) Bar() (err error) {

  foo.Begin()
  defer func() { foo.End(err) }()
  defer func() {
   if r := recover(); r != nil {
      debug.PrintStack()
      err = makeError(r)
   }
  } ()

  //some business code

  return
}

func (foo *Foo) End(err error) {  
  if err != nil {
    foo.Rollback()
  } else {
    foo.Commit()
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but I would strongly advise against it as it's severely unidiomatic Go.

Answer (score 3):

The parameters to a deferred function are immediately evaluated when `defer` is reached. Thats why you have to use a pointer if you defer `End` itself.

Instead you can use a closure. Your `Bar()` function would look like this:

```golang
func (foo *Foo) Bar() (err error) {
    foo.Begin()
    defer func() { foo.End(err) }()
    //some business code
    return
}
```

Here the value of `err` is evaluated once the deferred closure is executed.

If you're not stuck on using error returns, using panic and recover is the more idiomatic way in Go to handle such errors that require a rollback (like  Corey Ogburn recommended).

Comment: But if let it catch the panic, if will need more code in the cloure, which looks not good

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to use `recover()` to catch any `panic`s. What you have is very similar to that approach. [Check out the Go wiki about Panic and Recover](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PanicAndRecover)

```
func (foo *Foo) Bar() (err error) {

  foo.Begin()
  defer foo.End()

  //some business code
  err = fmt.Errorf("oh no, an error!") // set error so that Bar returns it even though it's caught
  panic(err)

  return
}

func (foo *Foo) End() {
  err := recover()
  if err != nil {
    foo.Rollback()
  } else {
    foo.Commit()
  }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/m_kpT5xtwe2

Comment: panic should not cross a package boundary, which make it not good to use so many panics. I will edit my question, add the recover situation

Comment: You're asking how to catch an error. This is the best practice. This is the language design. It won't cross package boundary if you panic and recover in whatever package has `foo` anyway.

Comment: but if the `business code` has something panic, then, Foo will return nil error

Comment: Because you have a named return, as long as you set your error before you panic it will still return something. In cases where you can't do that (another library panicking for example) [a deferred function can change the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248898/how-does-defer-and-named-return-value-work-in-golang)